# Issue with looping through excel files while one is opened by another user on a shared drive

Tags: excel, ssis

I created a package that loop through excel files and copy them over to a different folder. However, if one of the is open the package will fail. Any suggestions?

Comment: What error are you getting? Fail is a retaliative term and can mean so many things.

Comment: The File is open by another user

Comment: What would you want to happen in the event a file is locked by another user?  Also - always helps to post your existing code: it's much easier to offer an edit than write up the whole thing from scratch.

Comment: So what you are asking is how do you force close a file when it is being read by yourself or another user?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a script task first, something that goes through and closes all files in a particular folder, or a specific file. You could use something like below, it's vbscript but you could choose whatever scripting language you want.

`strComputer = "your-server"`
`strFolder = "Z:\fileshare"`

`On Error Resume Next`

`Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`
`Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")`

`Set objConnection = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer & "/LanmanServer")`
`Set colResources = objConnection.Resources`

`For Each objResource in colResources`
`strParent = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objResource.Path)`

`If LCase(strParent) = LCase(strFolder) Then`
`objShell.Run "openfiles /disconnect /s " & strComputer & " /id " &_`
`objResource.Name, 0, False`
`End If`
`Next`